# Share record to community based on condition

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities, salesforce-service-cloud, community-toolkit-mvvm

I have two object Schedule and Schedule Item which is in master-detail relationship.I want to show schedule item data on community site based on schedule item account field is match with site login user account if this is full fill these records only show on community site. how can i do this?

i am expecting schedule item list which has account same as currunt site login user account.

Comment: Have you tried sharing sets? They're good for community sharing data related to "this" portal-enabled contact's account. Or when all else fails could pull it off with a custom component?